# Replace newlines within <ul>-tag

Tags: php, regex

I have been battling with this for a while, because I guess I am not that awesome at regex. I have a few ul-tags and within those I would like to replace every /n newline with "" (nothing).
So, I would like to have this

```
other lines right here
[ul]
[li]line[/li]
[li]line 1[/li]
[li]line 2[/li]
[/ul]
other lines right here

[ul]
[li]line[/li]
[li]line 1[/li]
[li]line 2[/li]
[/ul]
other lines right here
```

changed to

```
other lines right here
[ul][li]line[/li][li]line 1[/li][li]line 2[/li][/ul]
other lines right here

[ul][li]line[/li][li]line 1[/li][li]line 2[/li][/ul]
other lines right here
```

I only want to get rid of the newlines within the ul-tag. How do I go about this issue I have?
Should I pre_match_all every ul tag and then format the matched content the way I would like it to be? Or is there any easier solution with preg_replace that takes care of all the newlines within the tag?

Thanks for the help already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at it a different way. the `[li]`s will always be inside a `[ul]` (well, hopefully!). So you can just match newlines either side of those:

`$string = preg_replace('/\R*(\[\/?li\])\R*/', '$1', $string);`

You could do the same with a couple of str_replaces:

```
$string = str_replace("\r\n[li]", "[li]", $string);
$string = str_replace("[/li]\r\n", "[/li]", $string);
```

Comment: great, thanks for making me feel like an idiot. Don't know why I couldn't have thought about it myself haha. But seriously, it worked. Do you know by chance why it doesn't get rid of the newline if I use \r\n, but if I use \n then it works? Anyhow, thanks

Comment: Sure, `\r\n` is Windows' version of line endings. Pretty much everything else uses just `\n`.See here for more info http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/difference-between-n-and-r-n note that in the regex above, `\R` is a PCRE character group which matches both.